# What's this post notice that exists on english.stackexchange.com but not on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, answers

Some short answers on [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com) are given a public notice like:

> We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Illustration from https://english.stackexchange.com/a/476570:
[image: answer with notice]

We don't have this feature on Stack Overflow, why?

Would there be a usage for similar public notices on Stack Overflow? For instance when an answer is made of pure code with zero explanation, we could imagine displaying:

> We're looking for detailed answers that provide some explanation. Don't just give a code-only answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with references. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Comment: I guess it's because code-only answers are still somewhat useful, it's easy to verify whether an answer is correct. It's less easy to verify a statement about a language, so references are more important, just like content on Wikipedia needs citations.

Comment: @Stijn [citation needed]

Comment: We really _should_ have this on SO. Pretty sure it was requested at some point. We need more tech-specific moderation like this.

Comment: @Stijn When the question contains 200 lines of code and an answer is a copy-and-paste of those 200 lines, with ten characters added to the middle of exactly one of those lines, with no description of what was changed, I don’t consider that useful or easy to read.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The notice is available on every site, including Stack Overflow:

[image: One of Cœur's answers with the notice]

Post owner will receive an inbox message labeled "*notice on answer*":

[image: notice on answer]

It's only available to moderators, who can add it when they deem it necessary; generally, small sites use it more readily, as larger sites are more able to downvote and delete lackluster answers, while also having less time to babysit such answers.

Comment: _"larger sites are more able to downvote and delete lackluster answers"_ This is a fair point. But it does seem like having these notices administrable by non-diamond user could be useful, given the oft-expressed desire to have reasons for downvotes. (And deletions are even more inscrutable).

Comment: OTOH, we have thousands and thousands of comments containing more specific guidance generated by thousands and thousands of non-diamond users via review, @Josh. That's something a lot of these sites don't have, and can't have without a handful of people posting most of 'em.

Comment: I love that the note was added to one of OP's recent answers. I laughed

Answer (score 7):

This exists on smaller network sites.  I've seen it on Anime.SE before several times.

The reason it wouldn't exist on a site like Stack Overflow is because the message doesn't scale.  Only diamond moderators can add a message like that and that only really works well when we're talking about tens or hundreds of posts that require it per *month*.  Stack Overflow gets over 8,000 questions a **day**, which would mean that a message like this couldn't  be delivered or conveyed *quickly* enough before the question has already been voted on.

Comment: Did you mean 8,000 a day?

Comment: @MikeM.:  [It's actually closer to 7,000](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic), but point taken.  I'll update.

Comment: Yeah, I was gonna point that out, too.

Comment: Closely related: [Let gold tag badge holders add post notices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278802) | [Allow high reputation users to add post notices (perhaps as a 30k privilege)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141931)

Comment: @JoshCaswell oh, so "_post notice_" is the official name? When I wrote the term in my question, I was attempting to describe the feature without knowing how it was really called.

Comment: Pretty sure that's it, @Cœur, yeah.

Comment: Well, it's not over 9000 @MikeM.

Comment: Mostly pointless trivia: there was (including now deleted questions) 8,218 questions created yesterday according to: `is:q created:1d deleted:all`...